# Distance between ticks and axes

Tags: plotting, version-7, ticks

I've created a plot using the following code:

```
ListPlot[{top, bottom},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[100]],
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"Number of non-zero bits", "alpha"},
 Axes -> False,
 LegendShadow -> None,
 PlotLegend -> {Style["exact value ", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 130],
    Style["estimated value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 130]},
 LegendOrientation -> Horizontal,
 LegendSpacing -> 1,
 (*LegendTextSpace->0.5,*)
 (*LegendBorderSpace->0.1,*)
 LegendSize -> {0.95, 0.15}, LegendPosition -> {-0.5, 0.6},
 LegendBorder -> None,
 LegendTextOffset -> {-0.8, 2.4},
 PlotRange -> {0, 20},
 ImageSize -> 7000,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Is there any way to increase the distance between the ticks and axes?

In my opinion, the ticks below the `x` `axis` are too close, and I would like to increase the distance between points `{0,2,4,6,8}` and the `x` axis.

Can anyone suggest a good way to do this that is **compatible with *Mathematica* 7**?

Comment: I think it's in the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) doc somewhere

Comment: I think it has been recently discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64400/include-more-padding-between-tick-marks-and-plot/64402#64402